# Why SDL_Window is an incomplete type?

Tags: android, c++, sdl-2

I am porting to SDL2 and the Android platform a C++ game that uses SDL 1.2. Everything went well so far except for one thing: when I try to access the fields of SDL_Window, the compiler tells me

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'SDL_Window {aka struct SDL_Window}'
```

I think my installation of SDL may be faulty. I have compiled SDL 2.0.0 from the source found on libsdl.org using the folloing command:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-18
```

Then, I have copied the freshly built `libSDL2.so` into `$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/lib` and the files in the `include/` directory in `$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/include/SDL`. These files are given to CMake and referenced by the game's code. I managed to convert every SDL calls and now I am stuck with this SDL_Window problem.

I did a quick search in SDL's source code and found that `SDL.h` includes `SDL_video.h` which contains a typedef `SDL_Window` on `struct SDL_Window`. Then I searched for this struct and did not find anything except in the original source archive, in a file named `src/video/SDL_sysvideo.h`. Since it is not a file of the API, I doubt I have to include it in my code.

So, how to find a definition of SDL_Window in SDL2, for Android (if this is relevant)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the problem is a lack of knowledge of SDL 2's API. Let's remember that one does not access the fields of `struct SDL_Window`: there are functions to get the size and the flags of the window, such as [SDL_GetWindowFlags](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFlags) and [SDL_GetWindowSize](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize).

So the problem is absolutely not related to the installation of the SDL or to Android builds. Sorry for the waste of time, people of the Web.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that you are expected to only deal in *pointers* to SDL_Window objects, and not actually put a full SDL_Window object on the stack.

Comment: I don't put my SDL_Window on the stack, I have the error when I try to access its members like in `SDL_Window* w; w->flags`.