# Incomplete Type is not Allowed QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning C++ with Qt. I have installed Qt 5.15 and am using VS2019. I have the below code (as per an example in a textbook I am working through):

```cpp
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    //declarations of variables
    int answer = 0;

    do{
        //local variables
        int factArg = 0;
        int fact(1);
        factArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Factorial Calculator", "Factorial of:", 1);
        cout << "User entered: " << factArg << endl;
        int i = 2;
        while (i <= factArg) {
            fact = fact * i;
            ++i;
        }
        QString response = QString("The factorial of %1 is %2.\n%3").arg(factArg).arg(fact).arg("Do you want to compute another factorial?");
        answer = QMessageBox::question(0, "Play again?", response, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    } while (answer == QMessageBox::Yes);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I am recieving the below error when creating an instance of `QApplication` as `app`:

`Incomplete Type is not Allowed`

I am also recieving the below error for the `QInputDialog` and `QMessageBox` classes:

`name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`

I am not sure why this is happening - presumably something with a namespace, but I am not sure what scope to provide. I have searched the web but to no avail.

**UPDATE**

Adding the below header references give `cannot open source file` error for each.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
```

I have also added suggestions from the comments to my code, now below:

```cpp
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    //declarations of variables
    int answer = 0;

    do{
        //local variables
        int factArg = 0;
        int fact(1);
        factArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Factorial Calculator", "Factorial of:", 1);
        cout << "User entered: " << factArg << endl;
        int i = 2;
        while (i <= factArg) {
            fact = fact * i;
            ++i;
        }
        QString response = QString("The factorial of %1 is %2.\n%3").arg(factArg).arg(fact).arg("Do you want to compute another factorial?");
        answer = QMessageBox::question(0, "Play again?", response, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    } while (answer == QMessageBox::Yes);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I am still recieving the same errors.

Comment: The compiler probably sees only a forward declaration for `QApplication`.  Try adding `#include <QApplication>` .

Comment: @G.M. that's what I tried initially, but when I add that reference I get the following error: `cannot open source file`

Comment: change `#include <QtGui>` to `#include <QtWidgets>`

Comment: @eyllanesc I get the same `cannot open source file QtWidgets`

Comment: @Dean also add `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - What does "Incomplete type not allowed" error mean, and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354611/c-what-does-incomplete-type-not-allowed-error-mean-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added those but still nothing..

Comment: @Dean `"but still nothing"` really doesn't help anyone else understand the problem.  Please edit your question to include the latest code (including .pro file if there is one) and the error messages you see verbatim.

Comment: @G.M. `but still nothing` implies no change from the original state with the additional code. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio installed? It seems to me that the cause of the error is that

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using Visual Studio 2019? Can I not use VS for Qt applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct headers to include are the following:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QInputDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
```

Once declaring these, the compiler accepts the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include some qt headers in the app... that is the meaning of the message

you just need to add  this to your code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
```

Comment: I get `cannot open source file` for each of these declarations..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to cut and paste a working program for you.

Qt seems to have a bunch of forward definitions. I can tell I'm missing the right include file if I try to get the IDE to actually help me select a method call. In short, you pretty much have to #include every widget type or other class you're going to use. I haven't run into any shortcuts.

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "MainWindow.h"

using namespace std;

/**
 * Main entry point.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```